# Using a ScrollView to scroll when ScrollView contains draggable cards - REACT NATIVE

Tags: react-native, scrollview, draggable

Hopefully you can help me with a bug I'm having a bit of bother sorting out. I'm working on a bug in an app built using React Native. It is building to IOS and Android. I have a ScrollView in a component that contains cards that are draggable objects.

These cards are dragged from the ScrollView they are in, up to buckets at the top of the screen. They disappear from the ScrollView and the remaining ones get reorganised so they stay ordered and neat. That works fine, you press on a box in the list and drag it to the buckets.

There is a bit of whitespace above the list of cards in the ScrollView. The ScrollView functionality works when swiping within this whitespace above the boxes, but I can't swipe on the boxes themselves without it beginning to drag the card.

Here is the component itself:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, ScrollView, Dimensions, Alert } from 'react-native';

import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import * as ConstStyles from '../../Consts/styleConsts';
import Bucket from '../Partials/bucketContainers';
import BusyIndicator from 'react-native-busy-indicator';
import loaderHandler from 'react-native-busy-indicator/LoaderHandler';
import CatCard from '../Partials/categoryCard';
import * as FeedActions from '../../../Redux/Feeds/actions';
import * as AuthFunctions from '../../Auth/functions';

export class SetupLikes extends Component {
  static navigatorStyle = ConstStyles.standardNav;

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.props.navigator.setOnNavigatorEvent(this.onNavigatorEvent.bind(this));
    this.card = [];
    let button = {
      leftButtons: [
        {
          title: 'Reset',
          id: 'reset'
        }
      ],
      rightButtons: [
        {
          title: this.props.newAccount ? 'Go' : 'Done',
          id: this.props.newAccount ? '' : 'skip',
          disabled: this.props.newAccount
        }
      ]
    };
    this.props.navigator.setButtons(button);
  }

  state = {
    xOffset: 0,
    positions: [],
    placedCards: [],
    loves: [],
    okays: [],
    hates: []
  };

  onNavigatorEvent(event) {
    setTimeout(async () => {
      if (event.type === 'NavBarButtonPress') {
        if (event.id === 'skip') {
          this.props.navigator.dismissModal({
            animationType: 'slide-down'
          });
        } else if (event.id === 'reset') {
          await this.imgTap();
        } else if (event.id === 'go') {
          await this.setInterests();
        }
      }
    }, 0);
  }

  async setInterests() {
    loaderHandler.showLoader('Setting your interests...');
    let newInterests = [];
    this.state.loves.forEach(function(element) {
      let cat = this.props.Feeds.categories[element];
      let newItem = {
        categoryid: cat.id,
        sentimentid: 1
      };
      newInterests.push(newItem);
    }, this);

    this.state.okays.forEach(function(element) {
      let cat = this.props.Feeds.categories[element];
      let newItem = {
        categoryid: cat.id,
        sentimentid: 0
      };
      newInterests.push(newItem);
    }, this);

    this.state.hates.forEach(function(element) {
      let cat = this.props.Feeds.categories[element];
      let newItem = {
        categoryid: cat.id,
        sentimentid: -1
      };
      newInterests.push(newItem);
    }, this);
    let sesId = this.props.User.sessionId;

    try {
      await this.props.dispatch(FeedActions.setMyInterests(sesId, newInterests));
      loaderHandler.hideLoader();
    } catch (err) {
      loaderHandler.hideLoader();
      Alert.alert('Uh oh', 'Something went wrong. Please try again later');
      return;
    }

    await AuthFunctions.setupAppLogin(this.props.dispatch, sesId);
  }

  async imgTap() {
    await this.setState({ placedCards: [], loves: [], okays: [], hates: [], positions: [] });
    setTimeout(() => {
      let cntr = 0;
      this.card.forEach(function(element) {
        cntr++;
        if (this.state.placedCards.includes(cntr - 1)) return;
        if (element) element.snapTo({ index: 0 });
      }, this);
    }, 5);
    this.props.navigator.setButtons({
      rightButtons: [
        {
          title: 'Go',
          id: '',
          disabled: true
        }
      ],
      animated: true
    });
  }

  cardPlaced(id, droppedIndex) {
    let newList = this.state.placedCards;
    newList.push(id);
    let cntr = 0;
    let offset = 0;
    let newPosIndex = [];
    this.props.Feeds.categories.forEach(cats => {
      let posY = (offset % 2) * -120 - 20;
      let xOffset = Math.floor(offset / 2);
      let posX = xOffset * 105 + 10;
      newPosIndex[cntr] = {
        x: posX,
        y: posY,
        offset: offset % 2
      };
      if (!newList.includes(cntr)) offset++;
      cntr++;
    });

    if (droppedIndex === 1) {
      let newLoves = this.state.loves;
      newLoves.push(id);
      this.setState({
        loves: newLoves,
        placedCards: newList,
        positions: newPosIndex
      });
    } else if (droppedIndex === 2) {
      let newOkays = this.state.okays;
      newOkays.push(id);
      this.setState({
        okays: newOkays,
        placedCards: newList,
        positions: newPosIndex
      });
    } else if (droppedIndex === 3) {
      let newHates = this.state.hates;
      newHates.push(id);
      this.setState({
        hates: newHates,
        placedCards: newList,
        positions: newPosIndex
      });
    }
  }

  reShuffle() {
    let cntr = 0;
    this.card.forEach(function(element) {
      cntr++;
      if (this.state.placedCards.includes(cntr - 1)) return;
      if (element) element.snapTo({ index: 0 });
    }, this);
  }

  setButton() {
    this.props.navigator.setButtons({
      rightButtons: [
        {
          title: this.props.newAccount ? 'Go' : 'Done',
          id: 'go'
        }
      ],
      animated: true
    });
  }

  onChangeSize(scrollWidth, scrollHeight) {
    let { height, width } = Dimensions.get('window');

    let farRight = this.state.xOffset + width;
    if (farRight > scrollWidth && farRight > 0) {
      let xOffset = scrollWidth - width;
      this.setState({ xOffset });
    }
  }

  onSnap(index, id) {
    this.cardPlaced(id, index);
    this.reShuffle();
    this.setButton();

    if (this.props.Feeds.categories.length === this.state.placedCards.length)
      setTimeout(async () => {
        await this.setInterests();
      }, 1);
  }

  renderCats() {
    let cntr = 0;
    var { height, width } = Dimensions.get('window');
    let res = this.props.Feeds.categories.map(item => {
      let ptr = cntr;
      let posY = (cntr % 2) * -120 - 20;
      let xOffset = Math.floor(cntr / 2);
      let posX = xOffset * 105 + 10;

      let vertPos = posY - 200 + ((cntr + 1) % 2) * -120;

      posX = this.state.positions[ptr] ? this.state.positions[ptr].x : posX;
      posY = this.state.positions[ptr] ? this.state.positions[ptr].y : posY;
      let off = this.state.positions[ptr] ? this.state.positions[ptr].offset : ptr % 2;

      cntr++;
      if (this.state.placedCards.includes(cntr - 1)) return null;

      item.key = cntr;
      return (
        <CatCard
          key={ptr}
          item={item}
          ptr={ptr}
          cntr={cntr}
          xOffset={this.state.xOffset}
          odd={off}
          posX={posX}
          posY={posY}
          yDrop={vertPos}
          screenWidth={width}
          onSnap={(res, id) => this.onSnap(res, id)}
          gotRef={ref => (this.card[ptr] = ref)}
        />
      );
    });

    cntr = 0;

    res.forEach(ele => {
      if (ele !== null) ele.key = cntr++;
    });
    let test = this.props.Feeds.categories[0];
    return res;
  }

  onScroll(res) {
    this.setState({ xOffset: res.nativeEvent.contentOffset.x });
  }

  render() {
    let colWidth = Math.ceil((this.props.Feeds.categories.length - this.state.placedCards.length) / 2) * 106;
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <View style={styles.bucketContainer1}>
          <Bucket
            type={'Love'}
            imageToUse={require('../../../img/waveLove.png')}
            height={this.state.loveHeight}
            count={this.state.loves.length}
            backgroundColor={'rgb(238, 136, 205)'}
          />
        </View>
        <View style={styles.bucketContainer2}>
          <Bucket
            type={'OK'}
            imageToUse={require('../../../img/waveOkay.png')}
            height={this.state.okayHeight}
            count={this.state.okays.length}
            backgroundColor={'rgb(250, 179, 39)'}
          />
        </View>
        <View style={styles.bucketContainer3}>
          <Bucket
            type={'Dislike'}
            imageToUse={require('../../../img/waveHate.png')}
            height={this.state.hateHeight}
            count={this.state.hates.length}
            backgroundColor={'rgb(112, 127, 208)'}
          />
        </View>
        <View style={styles.descriptionContainer}>
          <Text style={styles.dragLikesTitle}>Drag Likes</Text>
          <View style={styles.dividingLine} />
          <View>
            <Text style={styles.descriptionText}>Drag your likes and dislikes into the bucket above,</Text>
            <Text style={styles.descriptionText}>so we can generate your profile!</Text>
          </View>
        </View>
        <ScrollView
          ref={ref => (this.scroller = ref)}
          onMomentumScrollEnd={res => this.onScroll(res)}
          style={styles.scroller}
          horizontal={true}
          onContentSizeChange={(width, height) => this.onChangeSize(width, height)}
        >
          <View style={[styles.insideView, { width: colWidth }]}>{this.renderCats()}</View>
        </ScrollView>
        <BusyIndicator size={'large'} overlayHeight={120} />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    alignSelf: 'stretch',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: 'white'
  },
  bucketContainer1: {
    position: 'absolute',
    height: 130,
    width: 95,
    left: 10,
    top: 5
  },
  bucketContainer2: {
    position: 'absolute',
    height: 130,
    width: 95,
    top: 5
  },
  bucketContainer3: {
    position: 'absolute',
    height: 130,
    width: 95,
    right: 10,
    top: 5
  },
  insideView: {
    width: 2500,
    justifyContent: 'flex-end',
    overflow: 'visible'
  },
  cardContainer: {
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderColor: 'rgb(200,200,200)',
    borderRadius: 4,
    alignItems: 'center',
    width: 100,
    backgroundColor: 'white'
  },
  catImage: {
    height: 100,
    width: 100,
    borderTopRightRadius: 4,
    borderTopLeftRadius: 4
  },
  button: {
    backgroundColor: 'rgba(255,0,0,0.2)',
    width: 90,
    height: 50
  },
  scroller: {
    height: '100%',
    width: '100%',
    overflow: 'visible'
  },
  card: {
    position: 'absolute',
    overflow: 'visible'
  },
  descriptionContainer: {
    top: 140,
    width: '100%',
    alignItems: 'center',
    position: 'absolute'
  },
  dividingLine: {
    height: 1,
    width: '100%',
    borderWidth: 0.5,
    borderColor: 'rgb(150,150,150)',
    marginBottom: 5
  },
  dragLikesTitle: {
    fontFamily: 'Slackey',
    fontSize: 20,
    color: 'rgb(100,100,100)'
  },
  descriptionText: {
    fontSize: 12,
    textAlign: 'center',
    marginTop: 5
  }
});

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    User: state.User,
    Feeds: state.Feeds
  };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(SetupLikes);
```

Down at the bottom of the render function is where you'll see the ScrollView. It's rendering the categories via a function called `renderCats`.

It may be that because the cards I am rendering are draggable, that fixing this is an impossibility but I thought I would see if anyone has a better idea of how this may be fixed!

EDIT TO INCLUDE CatCard component...

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
    AppRegistry,
    StyleSheet,
    Text,
    View,
    ScrollView,
    TouchableOpacity,
    FlatList,
    Image,
    Platform,
    Animated,
    Easing,
    Dimensions
} from 'react-native';

import * as Consts from '../../Consts/colourConsts';
import * as ConstStyles from '../../Consts/styleConsts';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import Interactable from 'react-native-interactable';
import { CachedImage } from 'react-native-img-cache';

class CatCard extends Component {
    state = {
        initX: this.props.posX,
        initY: this.props.posY,
        zIndex: 1
    };

    onSnap(res, point) {
        if (res.nativeEvent.index === 0) {
            return;
        }
        let index = res.nativeEvent.index;

        setTimeout(() => {
            this.props.onSnap(index, point);
            let end = new Date();
        }, 100);
        Animated.timing(this.opacity, {
            toValue: 0,
            duration: 100,
            useNativeDriver: true
        }).start();
    }

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.opacity = new Animated.Value(1);
        this.height = Dimensions.get('window').height;
    }

    gotRef(ref) {
        this.props.gotRef(ref);
    }

    render() {
        let upY = this.props.posY + this.height + (1 - this.props.odd) * -120;
        upY = upY * -1;
        upY += 50;
        return (
            <Interactable.View
                ref={ref => {
                    this.gotRef(ref);
                }}
                onSnap={res => this.onSnap(res, this.props.ptr)}
                style={[styles.card, { zIndex: this.state.zIndex }]}
                animatedNativeDriver={true}
                dragToss={0.01}
                snapPoints={[
                    {
                        x: this.props.posX,
                        y: this.props.posY,
                        damping: 0.7,
                        tension: 300,
                        id: '0'
                    },
                    {
                        x: this.props.xOffset + 10,
                        y: upY,
                        tension: 30000,
                        damping: 0.1
                    },
                    {
                        x: this.props.xOffset + 10 + this.props.screenWidth * 0.33,
                        y: upY,
                        tension: 30000,
                        damping: 0.1
                    },
                    {
                        x: this.props.xOffset + 10 + this.props.screenWidth * 0.66,
                        y: upY,
                        tension: 30000,
                        damping: 0.1
                    }
                ]}
                initialPosition={{ x: this.state.initX, y: this.state.initY }}
            >
                <Animated.View
                    style={[styles.cardContainer, { opacity: this.opacity }]}
                >
                    <CachedImage
                        source={{ uri: this.props.item.imageUrl }}
                        style={styles.catImage}
                    />
                    <Text style={styles.cardText}>{this.props.item.name}</Text>
                </Animated.View>
            </Interactable.View>
        );
    }
}

CatCard.PropTypes = {
    count: PropTypes.any.isRequired,
    type: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    imageToUse: PropTypes.any.isRequired,
    height: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
    backgroundColor: PropTypes.string.isRequired
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    card: {
        position: 'absolute',
        overflow: 'visible'
    },
    cardContainer: {
        borderWidth: 1,
        borderColor: 'rgb(200,200,200)',
        borderRadius: 4,
        alignItems: 'center',
        width: 100,
        backgroundColor: 'white'
    },
    cardText: {
        fontFamily: 'Slackey',
        fontSize: 10
    },
    catImage: {
        height: 100,
        width: 98,
        borderTopRightRadius: 4,
        borderTopLeftRadius: 4
    }
});

export default CatCard;
```

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing `CatCard` it is hard to know how the dragging is implemented.  If you are doing raw `PanResponder` then you'll need to keep a something in state that keeps track of whether the `ScrollView` is scrolling and pass that down as a prop to `CatCard` which would then disallow the drag if the prop were true.

Alternatively, I'd suggest using [react-native-interactable](https://github.com/wix/react-native-interactable).  It's a little to wrap your head around but it's a great abstraction from `PanResponder`.  They have loads of examples and I have used it to make a swipeable list item that worked great, even with touchables inside the item.